# How to substring a number out of a string field using Python field calculator in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, attribute-table

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7

I want to substring numbers as text out of a string field into a new string field with field calculator so that I can use them for layer symbology. The field contains highway names such as 'I- 280' and 'State Rte 25' and I want only the '280' and '25' for a new field. Is there a Python conditional statement I can use that will substring the number regardless of digit length, placement (end or between text, eg, "State Rte 25 Bus")?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`isdigit()` string method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

```
''.join((s for s in !FULLNAME! if s.isdigit()))
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this string method to work. I tried  import isdigit()  as the pre-logic script code and copy/pasted the join expression as script for new field and an error is returned.

Comment: You don't need to import anything. `.isdigit()` is a method of any string.  What was the error? What is your dataset format (shapefile, FGDB feature class)?

Comment: Okay I got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to extract numerical values from a text.

In the field calculator, select the *Python* parser, and check *Show Codeblock*.

The regular expression package should be loaded first, so set the pre-logic script to:

```py
import re
```

and the script itself is:

```py
re.search("\d+", !FULLNAME!).group(0)
```

- `\d` means: match a digit (0–9)
- `+` means: match one or more of the previous
- `group(0)` returns the first match

There's no error handling, so this may fail if FULLNAME is empty, or does not contain a digit at all.

For more information see the documentation about [regular expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Wow, this completely worked! Thanks!

Comment: @kent Feel free to mark this as answer ;-)

Comment: You probably need to think about edge cases where there are two or more numbers seperated by text. Just make visual spot checks of your results where the `FULLNAME` looks  funny or non-standard, to see whether this really is a problem in your dataset.